# how to set html page size and page component with different screen resolution?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

Page body get the width as screens size. Then how to other components of the page sizing with the relevant screen size ?

Comment: [Media queries](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=media+queries&oq=media+qu&gs_l=hp.3.0.0l10.583.2883.0.5293.8.7.0.1.1.0.130.698.5j2.7.0....0...1c.1.32.hp..0.8.704.2-E8u5Rb4d8)

Comment: @user3249589 May you explain it in proper english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use media queries. Here i've posted just a simple demo.. look at my fiddle..

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vX8Eu/)

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px)
{
#header
{
    background: red;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:720px) and (max-width:959px)
{
#header
{
    background: green;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:719px)
{
#header
{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:479px)
{
#header
{
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

For more info about media queries you can go through these following links.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: And the use of display:flex is also a great idea

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate your question, from what i understood: you need to set the width of components to 100% to make them equal to page size.